# Unable to install requests using easy_install

Tags: python

Unable to install requests using easy_install and python version is 2.7.10

sudo easy_install-2.7 requests

Searching for requests
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/requests/

```
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/requests/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'requests' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for requests
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('requests')
```

Comment: You seem to have internet problems (Network is unreachable)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed to install 'requests' module.

Download get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

**Place the downloaded file get-pip.py under** Drive:.....\Python\Python37\
Open Command Prompt at 'Python37' folder 
and run

```
python get-pip.py
```

Once pip is successfully installed, run

```
pip install requests
```

This should solve all the issues and you should be able to import requests in Python Shell.

Answer (score -2):

run `pip install requests` to install package

Comment: That''s already mentioned in the [answer from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52688605/2745495). Also question mentions Python 2.7 and easy_install.